# angujar digest error loop when using boostrap alerts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using `angular-ui-boostrap` along with exception handler to show all application exceptions as an alert. The alert has dismiss-on-timeout set.

here's exception hander code (written in coffee):

```
$provide.decorator "$exceptionHandler", ['$delegate', 'alerts', ($delegate, alerts) ->
  (exception, cause) ->
    $delegate(exception, cause)
    if (alerts.elements.length < 5)
      alerts.add('danger', exception.message)
]
```

and the alert definition (written in jade):

```
uib-alert.animate-leave(ng-repeat="alert in c.alerts.elements" type="{{alert.type}}" close="c.alerts.close($index)" dismiss-on-timeout='5000') {{alert.message}}
```

**The problem is** if there's is an error during digest cycle I get an infinite loop. Because every time an error happens i add a new alert so digest cycle happens again, thus triggering new error.

And the same happens when the alert get's dismissed, the error is triggered, so new alert is added, and so on.

How can i solve it? Is it possible to update the alerts without triggering the whole digest cycle? But still update the alerts on view.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no way around that. But what you could do is overwriting angulars' error handler and counting the amount of errors during a certain time and stopping the application, if there is some kind of infinite error looping caused by digest cycle(all code in plain JS):

```js
function ExceptionService($log,$injector) {

        var errorLog = {};
        var applicationStopped = false;

        /**
         * override method to catch errors
         * @param exception
         * @param cause
         */
        function error(exception, cause) {
            // forward output to console
            $log.error.apply($log, arguments);
            if (!applicationStopped) {
              var cycleBreaked = _digestCycleBreakerCheck();
              if (!cycleBreaked) {
                //not many errors yet, just print to console or do nothing
              } else {
                //p.e. stop the whole angular application by destroying the rootScope
              }
            }
        }

        function _digestCycleBreakerCheck() {
            var cycleBreaked = false;
            if (Object.keys(errorLog).length === 0) {
                _resetErrorLog();
            } else {
                if (errorLog.lastErrorDate >= (_getCurrentTs() - 15)) {
                    errorLog.count += 1;
                    errorLog.lastErrorDate = _getCurrentTs();
                    if (errorLog.count >= 10) {
                        //break digest cycle!
                        cycleBreaked = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    //it has been the first error after more than x seconds
                    _resetErrorLog();
                }
            }
            return cycleBreaked;
        }

        function _resetErrorLog() {
            errorLog.count = 1;
            errorLog.lastErrorDate = _getCurrentTs();
        }

        function _getCurrentTs() {
            return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        }

        return (error);
    }
```

see: http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/